# How can Linux ptrace be unsafe or contain a race condition?

Tags: linux, sandbox, ptrace

I'd like to implement a sandbox by `ptrace()`ing a process I start and all its children would create (including grandchildren etc.). The `ptrace()` parent process, i.e. the supervisor. would be a simple C or Python program, and conceptually it would limit filesystem access (based on the path name and the access direction (read or write) and socket access (e.g. disallowing socket creation).

What should I pay attention to so that the `ptrace()`d process and its children (recursively) won't be able to bypass the sandbox? Is there anything special the supervisor should do at `fork()` time to avoid race conditions? Is it possible to read the filename arguments of e.g. `rename()` from child process without a race condition?

Here is what I've already planned to do:

- `PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK | PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORK | PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE` to avoid (some) race coditions when `fork()`ing
- disallow all system calls by default, and compose a whitelist of allowed system calls
- make sure that the `*at()` system call variants (such as `openat`) are properly protected

What else should I pay attention to?

Comment: So basically you are trying to replicate the ptrace-based backend of Systrace (http://www.systrace.org/) ?

Comment: Yes, my supervisor would work similarly to systrace. Unfortunately, systrace seems to be unmaintained, it doesn't compile cleanly, and it also seems to be buggy (it hanged indefinitely when I sandboxed GCC running GNU as).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The major problem is that many syscall arguments, like filenames, are passed to the kernel as userspace pointers.  Any task that is allowed to run simultaneously and has write access to the memory that the pointer points to can effectively modify these arguments after they are inspected by your supervisor and before the kernel acts on them.  By the time the kernel follows the pointer, the pointed-to contents may have been deliberately changed by another schedulable task (process or thread) with access to that memory.  For example:

```
Thread 1                           Supervisor             Thread 2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
strcpy(filename, "/dev/null");
open(filename, O_RDONLY);
                                   Check filename - OK
                                                          strcpy(filename, "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa");
(in kernel) opens "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

One way to stop this is to disallow calling `clone()` with the `CLONE_VM` flag, and in addition prevent any creation of writeable `MAP_SHARED` memory mappings (or at least keep track of them such that you deny any syscall that tries to directly reference data from such a mapping).  You could also copy any such argument into a non-shared bounce-buffer before allowing the syscall to proceed.  This will effectively prevent any threaded application from running in the sandbox.

The alternative is to `SIGSTOP` every other process in the traced group around every potentially dangerous syscall, wait for them to actually stop, then allow the syscall to proceed.  After it returns, you then `SIGCONT` them (unless they were already stopped).  Needless to say, this may have a significant performance impact.

(There are also analogous problems with syscall arguments that are passed on the stack, and with shared open file tables).

Comment: why does the copy solution prevent threaded applications? isnt the application expecting the system call to be "kinda" atomic, anyways?

Comment: @keppla: Because you can't create a non-shared memory region in a threaded application, since all the threads share the same VM.  The copy-to-non-shared workaround is for the case of syscall arguments in memory regions shared with other processes.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't ptrace only get notifications after-the-fact? I don't think you have a chance to actually stop the syscall from happening, only to kill it as fast as you can once you see something "evil".

It seems like you're more looking for something like SELinux or AppArmor, where you can guarantee that not even one illegal call gets through.

Comment: On Linux, there is PTRACE_SYSEMU, which can stop the syscall. Also thank you for mentioning alternatives. However, I fail to see why SELinux or AppArmor would be more secure -- provided that there are no bugs and race conditions. Is it a reasonable assumption?

Comment: A common way of disabling a syscall is changing it to getpid(2).