# Dynamic Linking ~ Limiting a DLL's system access

Tags: c++, dll, plugins, dynamic-linking

I know the question might seem a little vague but I will try to explain as clearly as I can.

In C++ there is a way to dynamically link code to your already running program. I am thinking about creating my own plugin system (For learning/research purposes) but I'd like to limit the plugins to specific system access for security purposes.

I would like to give the plugins limited access to for example disk writing such that it can only call functions from API I pass from my application (and write through my predefined interface) Is there a way to enforce this kind of behaviour from the application side?

If not: Are there other language's that support secure dynamically linked modules?

Comment: If your target OS is linux, this thread might be of interest : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414605/how-can-linux-ptrace-be-unsafe-or-contain-a-race-condition

Answer (score 2):

You should think of writing a plugin container (or a sand-box), then coordinate everything through the container, also make sure to drop privileges that you do not need inside the container process before running the plugin. Being run in a process means, you can run the container also as a unique user and not the one who started the process, after that you can limit the user and automatically the process will be limited. Having a dedicated user for a process is the most common and easiest way, it is also the only cross-platform way to limit a process, even on Windows you can use this method to limit a process.

Limiting access to shared resources that OS provides, like disk or RAM or CPU depends heavily on the OS, and you have not specified what OS. While it is doable on most OSes, Linux is the prime choice because it is written with multi-seat and server-use-cases in mind. For example in Linux you can use [cgroups](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt) [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cgroups) to limit CPU, or RAM easily for each process, then you will only need to apply it for your plugin container process. There is [`blkio`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/blkio-controller.txt) to control disk access, but you can still use the traditional [quote](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_quota) mechanism in Linux to limit per-process or per-user share of disk space.

Supporting plugins is an involved process, and the best way to start is reading code that does some of that, [Chromium sand-boxing](https://code.google.com/p/setuid-sandbox/) is best place I can suggest, it is very cleanly written, and has nice documentation. Fortunately the [code](https://code.google.com/p/setuid-sandbox/source/browse/) is not very big.

If you prefer less involvement with actual cgroups, there is an even easier mechanism for limiting resources, [docker](https://github.com/docker/docker) is fairly new but abstracts away low level OS constructs to easily contain applications, without the need to run them in Virtual Machines.

Answer (score 0):

To block some calls, a first idea may be to hook the system calls which are forbidden and others API call which you don't want. You can also hook the dynamic linking calls to prevent your plugins to load another DLLs. Hook disk read/write API to block read/write.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873658/how-can-i-hook-windows-functions-in-c-c), it may give you an idea to how can you forbid function calls.

You can also try to sandbox your plugins, try to look some open source sandbox and understand how they work. It should help you.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you really have to sandbox the environment in that the DLL runs. Building such a sandbox is not easy at all, and it is something you probably do not want to do at all. System calls can be hidden in strings, or generated through meta programming at execution time, so hard to detect by just analysing the binary. Luckyly people have already build solutions. For example google's project [native client](https://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) with the goal to generally allow C++ code to be run safely in the browser. And when it is safe enough for a browser, it is probably safe enough for you and it might work [outside of the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690526/can-i-run-googles-native-client-outside-of-the-browser).